# Selenium Test: Autenticate with WebAuthn through Windows Hello

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webauthn, fido, windows-hello

I'm trying to create a Selenium (java) test that goes through the WebAuthn authentication of a web service to which I'm already registered using Windows Hello Authentication via pin. is there a way to replicate login via windows hello (via pin) via Selenium?

I tried with the virtual authenticator with the following options, but it doesn't work and I don't understand how to set it up to make it work.

```
        VirtualAuthenticatorOptions options = new VirtualAuthenticatorOptions();
        options.setTransport(Transport.INTERNAL)
                .setProtocol(Protocol.CTAP2)
                .setHasUserVerification(true)
                .setIsUserVerified(true);
        return ((HasVirtualAuthenticator) driver).addVirtualAuthenticator(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Selenium cannot access your credentials stored in the Windows Hello authenticator. What you have there is setting up a new virtual authenticator (only supported on Chrome/Edge). It is an authenticator on its own, only implemented in the browser and does not communicate with your Windows Hello.

You could attempt automation at the operating system level in combination with Selenium, although I haven't personally experimented with this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the various experiments, I was trying not to use the virtual authenticaor, in this way the authentication popup appears, but I don't understand how to interact with it to replicate a login.